# Reuse of ActiveAdmin components

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have plenty of models and plenty of them need same setup (action buttons, member actions, panels etc). How could I reuse code on many places and keep the code DRY rather than copy/pasting same blocks of code all around.

E.g. I need this code on every resource:

```
member_action :purge_cache, method: :post do
    CacheManager.new(resource).purge_all
end
```

Comment: Create module in ActiveAdmin::Resource, check how they are doing it: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/resource/

Comment: big thanks @MrAleister - I would accept this as an answer actually :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create module in ActiveAdmin::Resource, [check how they are doing it](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/tree/master/lib/active_admin/resource)

Answer (score 3):

I found another way to do it:

Create `/app/admin/concerns/shared_stuff.rb`:

```
module SharedStuff
  def self.extended(base)
    base.instance_eval do
      member_action :purge_cache, method: :post do
        CacheManager.new(resource).purge_all
      end
    end
  end
end
```

WHerever you want same actions, you can just use:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Website do
  extend SharedStuff

  ...
```

You can add panels, filters, batch operations etc using this way easily ...

Credits goes to: http://tmichel.github.io/2015/02/22/sharing-code-between-activeadmin-resources/